# Replace regex string with the same content, and a span tag around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to place a span around every word inside of quotes, kind of like:

```
$('code').html($('code').html().replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '<span>/"(.*)?"/g</span>')
```

I can get it to replace all quoted words with a simple string but not with the original content with a span around it. Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the replacement string `$&` will get what the regexp matched, `$1` will get the first capture group, `$2` gets the second capture group, and so on. So:

```
$('code').html($('code').html().replace(/".*?"/g, '<span>$&</span>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/"(\w+)"/g, '<span>$1</span>')
```

You use special variables ($1, $2, etc.) to refer to the first (and second, etc.) matched item in parentheses.

Comment: You're losing the quotes in the replacement.

Comment: My bad, I thought that's what he wanted. Either way, answered now :-)